# Hive Lateral View Explode

Tags: hive

I have data that has a nested mapping in one of the fields. For example, the data is in a table called 'customers' and looks like this:

Name: Bill Jones

Address: {"billing":{"street":"123 Main", "city":"Chicago", "state":"IL"},"shipping":{"street":"432 Copper", "city":"New York", "state":"NY"}}

What sort of query can I write to explode the entire dataset out?

I started with the following:

```
select name, key1, value1
from customers
lateral view explode(address) table1 as key1, value1
```

That got me part of the way there. It splits up the "billing" and "shipping" fields. However, I can't explode out the remaining. I tried this, but got an error message:

```
select name, key1, key2, value2
from customers
lateral view explode(address) table1 as key1, value1
lateral view explode(value1) table2 as key2, value2
```

I know I'm not doing it right, but not sure what the fix is?

Thanks,

Chetan

Comment: it would be useful if you can provide the table structure.

Comment: Sure, the field names are: name, address, email, phone, spend. The field that is stored as a nested mapping is address (similar to the example above)

Comment: and the date types for each one?the create table statement would be better :D

Comment: ah, the table is already pre-loaded in my database. name (string), addresses (map<string,struct<street1:string,street2:string,city:string,state:string>>), email (string), phone (string), spend (int)

Comment: sorry, i'm a little new to stack overflow, so apologies if i am breaking a bunch of etiquette here

Answer (score 7):

#### Demo

```
create table customers (Name string, addresses map<string,struct<street1:string,street2:string,city:string,state:string>>);

insert into customers 
select  'Bill Jones'
       ,map
        (
            'billing'   ,named_struct('street1','123 Main'   ,'street2','' ,'city','Chicago'  ,'state','IL')
           ,'shipping'  ,named_struct('street1','432 Copper' ,'street2','' ,'city','New York' ,'state','NY')
        )
;
```

---

**Option 1**

```
select  name

       ,addresses['billing'].street1   as billing_street1 
       ,addresses['billing'].street2   as billing_street2
       ,addresses['billing'].city      as billing_city   
       ,addresses['billing'].state     as billing_state  
                                       
       ,addresses['shipping'].street1  as shipping_street1
       ,addresses['shipping'].street2  as shipping_street2
       ,addresses['shipping'].city     as shipping_city   
       ,addresses['shipping'].state    as shipping_state  

from    customers
;
```

---

```
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
|    name    | billing_street1 | billing_street2 | billing_city | billing_state | shipping_street1 | shipping_street2 | shipping_city | shipping_state |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Bill Jones | 123 Main        |                 | Chicago      | IL            | 432 Copper       |                  | New York      | NY             |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

**Option 2**

```
select  name 
       ,key             as address_type
       ,value.street1
       ,value.street2
       ,value.city
       ,value.state
        
from    customers
        lateral view explode(addresses) a  
;
```

---

```
+------------+--------------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
|    name    | address_type |  street1   | street2 |   city   | state |
+------------+--------------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
| Bill Jones | billing      | 123 Main   |         | Chicago  | IL    |
| Bill Jones | shipping     | 432 Copper |         | New York | NY    |
+------------+--------------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: ...This one is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, you have the following structure

name (string), addresses (map>), email (string), phone (string), spend (int)

What you have here, is a map of string, structure not a map of maps, so you can query the data in the folllowing way

```
select name, key1, 
value1.street1,
value1.street2,
value1.city,
value1.state
from customers
lateral view explode(address) table1 as key1, value1
```